# Code works in Chrome but not IE11

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in MVC 5 and cannot figure out why it errors when running in IE. Works fine in chrome. I've read article about the order of jquery, bootstrap, etc and tried those fixes but they didn't help. Does anyone know why this will not work?

BundleConfig.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace PaceArt_Document_Viewer
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit     https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and     learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at     https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I've tried all the fixes but nothing seems to work. The debugger says it's the first $ preceding '$(document.ready....'. I've put the script src tags inline calling jquery, validate and modinizr but still getting the same error.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        @{
            var folderPath = Request.Url.Segments.Last();
            string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            string urlSegment = url.Substring(folderPath.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            string urlFilePath = url.Remove(urlSegment.Length - 4);
        }
        var filePath = "@folderPath";//02939e1a435e46169076a0f9c5960647 //3740da10833b4de481a3e558a7a69889"; 
        var url = "@Url.Action("GetPDFInline", new { filePath = -1 })";
        var result = url.replace(-1, $("#pdfDisplayPathInline1").val());
        $("#pdfDisplay").attr('src', result)

        $('.pdfLinks').on('click', function () {
            var value = $(this).text();
            var valueUpdate = value.slice(0, -4);
            var path;
            var filePathTrim = filePath.slice(0, -4);
            if (filePathTrim == valueUpdate) {
                path = filePathTrim + ".pdf";
            } else {
                path = filePathTrim + "\\" + valueUpdate + ".pdf";
            }
            var url = "@Url.Action("GetPDFAttachments", new { filePathlink = -1 })";
            var result = url.replace(-1, path);
            $("#pdfDisplay").attr('src', result)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What specifically does not work? Do you get any error?

Comment: if js related, could be missin ; (colon) in this statement $("#pdfDisplay").attr('srcdoc', result) and also $("#pdfDisplay").attr('srcdoc', result)

Comment: Sorry, the console shows:"Unable to get property 'fn' of undefinded or null reference"

Comment: I just noticed it also says jquery is missing an expected identifier and "The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a function object"

Comment: Before anything I would suggest hitting ctrl F5 in ie to clear the cache

Comment: Ok, ctrl + F5 still yields the same result

Comment: check your network tools to see if the jquery file is downloaded correctly when the page first loads. BTW your c# code is largely irrelevant to this, apart from the BundleConfig

Comment: It's probably jQuery validate. Add the script tag for validate directly on the view with the error.

Answer (score -1):

IE could be struggling with the correct version of jQuery due to this line in your bundle -

```
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"
```

Instead of using your jQuery bundle try using a script tag with the appropriate version of jQuery (full version not min)

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

If that works then amend your bundle to suite...